# ¿Como transformar en un matriz panda dataframe una consulta SQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Quiero establecer un array desde un base de datos postgresql para que tenemos por el encabezamiento los `eclipse_id` y por el lado los `subscriber_id`.

```
> data.head(6).ix[:,2:8]

   1222  52582       45552        122  589  568
0     0      0           0          0    0    0
1     0      0           1          0    0    0
2     0      0           0          0    0    0
3     0      3           0          0    0    0
4     0      0           0          0    0    0
5     0      0           0          0    5    0
```

Vendría de una base de datos `swipe` con atributos `eclipse_id`, `subscriber_id` y `state` pero quiero solamente contar los que valen 2,3,5,6,8,9.

Aqui esta la consulta SQL, no sé si hay una otra manera hacerla :

```
SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id
```

No sé como hacerlo desde Datagrip con un fichero que abriremos como asi :

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

O directamente desde Jupyter notebook...

#### Con Datagrip

Por lo momento tengo sobre datagrip :

```
1   6874    179
1   10205   13
1   9958    13
1   9639    161
1   11128   185
```

Utilisaba Dump Data en la derecha para obtenerlo en el `/home` pero no funciona: tengo eso :

```
Cannot write file: /home/SELECT__COUNT__swipe_state__swipe_eclips.csv
```

#### Con Jupyter

Intento hacerlo desde Jupyter notebook pero no estoy capaz imprimir los resultados

```
import traceback
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from operator import *
import pandas as pd

now = datetime.now()

print now


params = {
  'database': 'escondida...',
  'user': '',
  'password': '',
  'host': '',
  'port': ''
}

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""
    -- nombre de personnes ayant telecharge notre produit 
    SELECT  COUNT (swipe.state),swipe.eclipse_id, swipe.subscriber_id FROM swipe
  WHERE swipe.state= 2 OR swipe.state = 3 or swipe.state=5 OR swipe.state =6 or swipe.state=8 or swipe.state=9
    GROUP BY swipe.subscriber_id,swipe.eclipse_id;
    """)
    n = cur.fetchall()
    print "\nnombre de personnes ayant telecharge notre produit  \n"
    print n

except psycopg2.Error as e:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
    print e
    print e.pgcode
    print e.pgerror
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

Tengo este los datos de `n` :

```
[(1L, 6874, 179), (1L, 10205, 13), (1L, 9958, 13), (1L, 9639, 161), (1L, 11128, 185), (1L, 9856, 190), (1L, 10663, 296), (1L, 6694, 158), (1L, 10294, 13), (1L, 6845, 156), (1L, 10431, 13), (1L, 7022, 156), (1L, 6943, 172), (1L, 9862, 189), (1L, 7645, 189), (1L, 7025, 156), (1L, 9618, 190), (1L, 10056, 13),...
```

Puedo hacer :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(listado)
print df1
```

me da :

```
count  eclipse_id  subscriber_id
0         1      6874.0            179
1         1     10205.0             13
2         1      9958.0             13
3         1      9639.0            161
```

[image: captura del resultado]

Pero no es una matriz.

Intento tambien :

```
pd.DataFrame(data=listado[1:,0],
            index=listado[2:,0]
            columns=listado[3:,0])
```

Pero me respuesta :

```
  File "<ipython-input-33-f87ac772eb69>", line 3
    columns=listado[3:,0])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

El proyecto esta hacer una un sistema de recomendación basada en el usuario siguiendo [el artículo del blog de Salem Marafi](http://www.salemmarafi.com/code/collaborative-filtering-with-python/comment-page-1/#comment-115378) o el de [analyticsvidhya.com](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/06/quick-guide-build-recommendation-engine-python/).

Comment: Voy a intentar adivinar... ¿Tu pregunta es por qué no se ve "como tabla" el resultado? En ese caso la respuesta es porque estás usando `print`, que implícitamente causa que el dataframe se convierta a cadena formateada "ascii". Si quieres volcarlo como tabla, omite el print, o us `display(df)` (necesitas un `from IPython import display` antes)

Answer (score 1):

Pues "n" al momento de imprimir ya es un array, no se que deseas.

```
listado = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1], "subscriber_id": elem[2]} for elem in n]
print(listado[0]['count'])  # Esto deberia imprimir 1L
```

Eso te dara una lista de diccionarios.

Comment: Gracias, pero con eso obteno cosas que no parecen ser una matriz como `0     {u'count': 1, u'subscriber_id': 179, u'eclipse... 1     {u'count': 1, u'subscriber_id': 13, u'eclipse_...` me gustaría obtenerlo como [eso](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FTge.png)

Comment: Te lo repito esos datos que tienes SON UNA MATRIZ(una lista de listas o arreglo de arreglos en otros lenguajes), Lo que tu buscas es pintarlo graficamente, te recomiendo cambies el titulo de la pregunta. Ahi se esta usando una interfaz grafica si quieres emularlo desde consola te recomiendo instalar la libreria tabulate https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate , o  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable o https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable , repito cambia la pregunta tu no buscas una MATRIZ buscas pintar una TABLA saludos

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza from_records para importar listas a DataFrames

```
import pandas as pd
n = [('1L', 6874, 179), ('1L', 10205, 13)]
labels=['count','eclipse_id','subscriber_id']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(n, columns=labels)
df.head()
```

[image: resultado]